# Calculating run times of programs with asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithms, summation, asymptotics, computational-complexity

When calculating the run time of programs using asymptotic notation, I know how to set up the sums for things like for loops, but I'm getting stuck on summing them up.

Sorry if this is a dumb question but say we have something like

```
for i=4 to n^2
   for j = 5 to 3i log (i)
      s = s + ij
```

I would set this up with outer loop = sum from i=4 to n^2, inner loop sum from j = 5 to 3i log i, and finally a constant.  I'm getting hung up on how to sum everything up.  Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: First consider the inner loop. How many iterations does this take, *for fixed* $i$? Then consider the outer loop, and take the sum of the number of iterations for each value of $i$.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to determine runtime is to use summations.  Each loop becomes a sum, where the lower index is the starting value of the loop and the upper index is the ending value of the loop.  Because you're performing a constant time operation in the innermost loop, we are simply summing $1$:
\begin{align}\sum_{i=4}^{n^2} \sum_{j=5}^{3i\lg i} 1 &= \sum_{i=4}^{n^2}3i\lg i - 5 + 1\\
&\approx\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}i\ln i\end{align}
(I'm using $\approx$ to slide between expressions that are asymptotically equivalent throughout the problem.)

The last summation above is kind of difficult (its solution involves the [hyperfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html) function).  So, we switch to an approach that is accessible to more students: a summation may be approximated by an integral.  So, we now compute:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}i\ln i&\approx \int_1^{n^2}x\ln x\,dx \\
&\approx x^2\ln x + \mathcal O(x^2)\Bigg |_1^{n^2}\\
&\approx n^4\ln n
\end{align}

So, your program executes with $\mathcal{O}(n^4\ln n)$ time complexity.

Answer (score -1):

Consider two loops $A$ and $B$ that are not nested. The body of A executes $n$ times and the body of B executes $k$ times. If we execute $B$ in the body of $A$, then $A$ still executes $n$ times, but $B$ executes whenever the body of $A$ executes. The body of $B$ executes $k$ times whenever the body of $A$ executes, and the body of $A$ executes $n$ times, so the body of $B$ executes $n \cdot k$ times.

When calculating the running time of an algorithm, you want to compare the number of steps in the algorithm to the input size. Say the input size for the algorithm $B$ nested inside of $A$ is $n$. You first want everything in terms of the input size, so say we know that $k = n/2$. Then the number of steps taken is $n \cdot k = 1/2 \cdot n^2 = c \cdot n^2 = O(n^2)$.

I hope this helps.